# Chemical Potential of an electron or positron in a pair production reaction

Tags: plasma-physics, partition-function, chemical-potential, pair-production

In the Thorne and Blandford Modern Classical Physics text there is an exercise that walks you through deriving the density-temperature limit for pair production in plasmas. To do this they consider a scattering reaction that produces a pair:

$e^- + p \to e^- + p + e^- + e^+$.

We assume this reaction is in statistical equilibrium, so the chemical potentials (including rest masses) are equal on the right and the left which suggests:

$\mu_- = - \mu_+$.

I was able to show that the number densities of the electrons and positrons in this reaction should be given by:

$n_\pm = \frac{2}{h^3} (2\pi m_e k_B T)^{3/2} \exp\left(\frac{\tilde{\mu}_\pm - m_ec^2}{k_BT}\right)$,

However the text suggests you should be able to write out the number density of positrons relative to protons in the following form:

$\frac{n_{+}}{n}=\frac{1}{2 y\left[y+\left(1+y^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]}$
where

$y \equiv \frac{1}{4} n \lambda^{3} e^{m_{e} c^{2} /\left(k_{B} T\right)}, \quad$ and $\quad \lambda \equiv \frac{h}{\sqrt{2 \pi m_{e} k_{B} T}}$.

**What is unclear to me is how can we write the chemical potential of a positron/electron in this plasma?**

*Attempted Solution*

In Statistical Mechanics by Pathria they suggest in a chemical reaction, they suggest you can describe the chemical potential (without rest mass) as:

$\mu_{A}=\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial N_{A}}\right)_{T, V}=\varepsilon_{A}+k T \ln \left(n_{A} \lambda_{A}^{3}\right)-k T \ln j_{A}(T)$
where $A$ is the species, $\varepsilon_A$ is the groundstate energy of the molecule, $n_A$ is number density, $\lambda_A$ is de Broglie wavelength, and $j_A$ is the partition function for internal degrees of freedom of the molecule. If I want to use this to describe an electron in this scattering reaction, would there only be one internal degree of freedom for the particle, so the partition function would simply be:

$j_e = \exp(\varepsilon_e/k_BT)$?
where $\varepsilon_e$ is simply the energy of the electron such that the chemical potential is reduced to just one term? Then the Chemical potential (including rest mass) would become:

$\tilde{\mu}_- = kT\ln(n_e\lambda_e^3) + m_ec^2$

However I don't seem to be able to derive the correct result using this. Any help would be appreciated.